# Create and save a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This creates a workbook as expected in the xls format, but when I attempt to open the newly created workbook I receive an error. If you click Yes the file opens as expected.

```vb
Sub CreateSheets()
Dim PathName As String
Dim strName As String
Dim FromNum As Integer
Dim ToNum As Integer
Dim a_counter As Integer

On Error GoTo Err

FromNum = Application.InputBox("Enter Start number")
ToNum = Application.InputBox("Enter End number")
'PathName = "\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\"

PathName = "U:\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\"
'PathName = "I:\Alba Work\"
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

For a_counter = FromNum To ToNum

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F3") = a_counter
    strName = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value
    strName = CStr(a_counter)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=PathName & strName & ".xls" ', FileFormat:= _
      xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
      , CreateBackup:=False

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next a_counter
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

I tried amending the file format to .xlsx and it fails.

---

I removed the command which was trying to save the file as .xls and replaced it with the FileFormat:=52 as it needs to be saved as a macro enabled workbook ...

Comment: The file format and extension of '1.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe.

Comment: You can't use `SaveCopyAs` to change the workbook format, if that's what you're trying to do here.  Note that `SaveCopyAs' only has a single parameter (file name/path) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas

Comment: Thanks Tim for the pointer, I am trying to change the workbook format and the code is based on what I created several years ago. I am a bit ring rusty when it comes to Macros so looking for some pointers as to what I can do to change that function

Comment: Does your workbook have multiple worksheets?  If Yes then maybe `SaveCopyAs` to create a temporary copy without changing the format, then open that temporary file and do a `SaveAs` to create the final file with the required format.  If only a single worksheet then copy that to create a new workbook and you can save that in the required format.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, I removed the command which was trying to save the file as .xls and replaced it with the FileFormat:=52 as it needs to be saved as a macro enabled workbook for the copies to send further info to a master job sheet using another Macro